# HTML thinks end of PHP tag is end of html form tag

Tags: php, html

so I have my HTML Form tag with attributes, which include method, action, id, and in the method tag i have PHP code, however, I believe HTML is thinking the end of the PHP script is the end of the HTML tag, so nothing seems to be working

```
<form method="post" action= "<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="contact_div" >
    Name: <span id="error"> * </span> <br/> <input type="text" name="name">
```

I feel like I should just get
Name: * [input]

but instead, I'm getting
"id="contact_div" > Name * [input]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but try inserting a space after `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];` and before the `?>`

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, and doesn't think anything. The browser can't see the closing PHP tag because it won't be rendered by PHP when it generates the page, unless you're not actually executing the PHP at all.

Comment: Have you not closed previous <?php tag by any chance?

Comment: Remove the space after 'action='

Comment: Give full html form and the php code for better understanding. I also suggest to improve the format of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this piece of code inside another piece of `<?php  ?>`?
You should place it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make this slight change it will do the job...
The code which u were using in action it starts with double quotes and then there was a double quote at $_SERVER[" which was completing the quote.

' id="contact_div" >
    Name:  *

Comment: Nope, inside <?php /*...*/ ?> you can have double quote which will not complete the html double quote. Try it out.